# While loop when variable is not defined

Tags: regex, bash, shell, loops, while-loop

**Scenario**. I have this code:

```
regexp="[^0-9A-Za-z]+"
while [[ $var =~ $regexp ]]
do
{
    var=$(dialog --inputbox "File name (number and letters only): " 12 60 --stdout)
}
done
echo $var
```

**Condition**:

The variable ***var*** should not be set (is not set) before ***while*** statement;

**Target**:

Leave ***while*** statement only when the variable has alphanumeric values.

---

But if I try to run it don't work. It works if I set up variable ***var***, e.g:

```
regexp="[^0-9A-Za-z]+"
var="_"
while [[ $var =~ $regexp ]]
do
{
    ...
```

Now, how to run that code without set up variable ***var***?

Comment: There is an error in your logics here: you **must** initialize the `var` before `while` or place this `while` into `while true; ... done`. The regex to match 1 or more alphanumeric characters is `[0-9A-Za-z]+`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `while true` loop and `break` if the condition is met:

```
while true; do
    # Read variable
    var=$(dialog ...)

    # Check regex and break if it matches
    [[ "$var" =~ $regexp ]] && break
done
```

Btw, the regex should be:

```
regexp="^[[:alnum:]]+$"
```

Comment: sorry, but if I use this solution I lose exit code of dialog tool.

Comment: Sorry, but don't work: endless loop. Try yourself using words test and _test

Comment: I did. *test* is valid meaning it would break the lop. *_test* is not. Are you using the regex I've posted?

Comment: You can save the exit status of `dialog` with `status=$?` immediately following the `var=...` line.

Comment: Sorry, endless loop. But it's run properly removing double quote in "Check regex and break if it matches", e.g. with this LOC: [[ $var =~ $regexp ]] && break. Why? Any Idea?

Comment: @mikilinux You are right! `$regex` should not being quoted in the conditional!

Answer (score 2):

You can use **default variable value**:

```
regexp="[^0-9A-Za-z]+"
while [[ ${var:-#} =~ $regexp ]]; do
   var=$(dialog --inputbox "File name (number and letters only): " 12 60 --stdout)
done
echo "$var"
```

`${var:-#}` will return `#` of `var` is null or unset otherwise it returns variable's value.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking if `var` matches an illegal value, check that is *doesn't* match a legal value.

```
# Drop the ^ from the beginning of the character class
regexp="[0-9A-Za-z]+"
# Negate the condition with !
while [[ ! $var =~ ^$regexp$ ]]
do
    var=$(dialog --inputbox "File name (number and letters only): " 12 60 --stdout)
done
echo $var
```

There is also the little-seen `until` command (as well as a predefined character class that includes letters and numbers while respecting the current locale):

```
until [[ $var =~ ^[[:alnum:]]+$ ]]; do
```

Comment: sorry, but don't work. Try yourself using words "test" and "_test". With test get out of while statement, with _test get out of while statement ...but only with test should be out while statement.